# TypeScript - Mongoose document middleware compilation error

Tags: typescript, mongoose

#### Issue

I just installed TypeScript 3.4 and noticed that some of my Mongoose middleware functions were no longer passing type checking.

**TypeScript output**

```
model.ts:19:8 - error TS7017: Element implicitly has an 'any' type because type 'typeof globalThis' has no index signature.

19   this.modified = new Date();
```

**Schema definition**

```
Schema.pre("save", next => {
    this.modified = new Date();
    next();
});
```

#### What I've tried

TSLint suggested first casting `this` to a `unknown` then casting it to the model type.

```
Schema.pre("update", next => {
    (<Model>(<unknown>this)).modified = new Date();
    next();
});
```

This seems to work, but it's not exactly neat or easy to understand.

#### Question

How can I solve this in a nicer way? I don't want to disable any TS rules.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hy, the best way is shown in the related git issue :
https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/5046

As explained there :

> So this has nothing to do with Typescript. The problem is that you are
>   using fat arrow syntax to define mongoose methods and hooks. Don't do
>   that. If you use a fat arrow function to define a pre save hook, it
>   has no lexical scope and cannot be bound to a given context.

So replace `next =>` by `function(next) {}` and it should work properly

Answer (score 1):

Replacing `=>` with `function(next) {}` seemed to get the correct value for this. But still typescript throws error if you try to access `this.username`

`Error: TS2339: Property 'username' does not exist on type 'Document'.`

To overcome this you could either use getter and setter like `this.get('username')` and `this.set('username', 'John')` or you could do below

```
export interface IUser extends mongoose.Document {
  usernname: string,
  password: string
}

const usersSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  username: String,
  password: String,
});

usersSchema.pre<IUser>("save", function(next) {
  const user = this;
  // user.password and user.username exists here.
  next();
});

const User = mongoose.model<IUser>("Users", usersSchema);
```